# How do I create an IndexTemplate using ElasticSearch Nest Version 7.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Elasticsearch Nest version 6.5.1 has the method: IElastiClient.PutIndexTemplateAsync which allows for the creating of an IndexTemplate.

I have just upgraded to Elasticsearch Nest version 7.4.0 and this method has been deleted with no guidance given about a replacement. Please can someone explain how to create an IndexTemplate using the Elasticsearch NET API version 7.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method with other ones related to index opeartions was moved into `client.Indices`.

```
await client.Indices.PutTemplateAsync(..)
```

You can read more about the reasoning of this change in the [official blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-7-0-now-ga) (see "Namespaced API methods and Upgrade Assistant" section). Furthermore, you can install [NEST.7xUpgradeAssistant](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.7xUpgradeAssistant/) package wich will help you with 6.x to 7.x transition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-breaking-changes.html#_the_upgrade_assistant and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#upgrading-from-6x-to-7x and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/7.0.0

Comment: You have answered my question perfectly.Thank you very much.